# Merge numpy arrays with different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with shape (100,9,17,2). I need to transform it to (100,15,17,2) adding zeros in missing cells. I created a zeros(100,6,17,2) but I can't merge them. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy's concatenate function.

```
result = np.concatenate([input_array, np.zeros((100, 6, 17, 2), dtype=input_array.dtype)], axis=1)
```

The `axis` argument is the argument over which you want the dimensions to be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import numpy as np
 a = np.array ([[1, 2], [2, 2]])
 b = np.array ([[1, 2], [2, 2], [1,2]])
 print (a.shape, b.shape)
```

output: (2,2), (3,2)

Now, to concatenate both array mention axis as well.

```
c = np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)

output: array([[1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you create an array containing zeros using the reference shape:

```
c = np.zeros((100, 15, 17, 2))
```

then insert the other array in the correct elements:

```
c[:a.shape[0],b.shape[1]:,:a.shape[2],:a.shape[3]] = a
```

Finally add them up:

```
merged = b + c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, [`numpy.apply_along_axis()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) and `numpy.pad()`

```py
new_array = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.pad(x,(0,6)), 1, input_array)
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers